# C# DES Decryption Issue

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, des

I've a problem implementing symmetric encryption algorithm,the problem is that: randomly the decrypted data is incorrect(rubbish) and only happening on the deployment environment(IIS8 on Win Server 2012 R2)

I started with an AES implementation,when the problem showed up i did a remote debugging on the server and confirmed same encrypted input with the same key/vector is giving different result(rubbish) from my development environment(visual studio on win10 x64)

I've converted to DES but still the same problem exists,below is my DES class for reference:

```
public class SimpleDES
{
    // Change these keys
    private byte[] Key = { x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x};
    private byte[] Vector;
    private string salt = "********";

    private ICryptoTransform EncryptorTransform, DecryptorTransform;
    private System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTFEncoder;

    public SimpleDES(string iVector)
    {
        this.Vector = this.StrToByteArray(iVector);
        Array.Resize(ref this.Vector, 16);

        //This is our encryption method
        DESCryptoServiceProvider ObjDES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();


        //Create an encryptor and a decryptor using our encryption method, key, and vector.
        EncryptorTransform = ObjDES.CreateEncryptor(this.Key, this.Vector);
        DecryptorTransform = ObjDES.CreateDecryptor(this.Key, this.Vector);

        //Used to translate bytes to text and vice versa
        UTFEncoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    }


    /// ----------- The commonly used methods ------------------------------    
    /// Encrypt some text and return a string suitable for passing in a URL.
    public string EncryptToString(string TextValue)
    {
        return ByteArrToString(Encrypt(TextValue + salt));
    }

    /// Encrypt some text and return an encrypted byte array.
    public byte[] Encrypt(string TextValue)
    {
        //Translates our text value into a byte array.
        Byte[] bytes = UTFEncoder.GetBytes(TextValue);
        return EncryptBin(bytes);
    }


    /// Encrypt some binary and return an encrypted byte array.
    public byte[] EncryptBin(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        //Used to stream the data in and out of the CryptoStream.
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            /*
             * We will have to write the unencrypted bytes to the stream,
             * then read the encrypted result back from the stream.
             */
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, EncryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                #region Write the decrypted value to the encryption stream
                cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                #endregion

                #region Read encrypted value back out of the stream
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                encrypted = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                memoryStream.Read(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
                #endregion

                //Clean up.
                cs.Close();
            }
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    /// The other side: Decryption methods
    public string DecryptString(string EncryptedString)
    {
        return Decrypt(StrToByteArray(EncryptedString)).Replace(salt, string.Empty);
    }

    /// Decryption when working with byte arrays.    
    public string Decrypt(byte[] EncryptedValue)
    {
        Byte[] decryptedBytes;
        using (MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream decryptStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, DecryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                #region Write the encrypted value to the decryption stream
                decryptStream.Write(EncryptedValue, 0, EncryptedValue.Length);
                decryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                #endregion
                #region Read the decrypted value from the stream.
                encryptedStream.Position = 0;
                decryptedBytes = new Byte[encryptedStream.Length];
                encryptedStream.Read(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
                #endregion
            }
        }
        // remove trailing zero bytes
        //int lastIndex = Array.FindLastIndex(decryptedBytes, b => b != 0);
        //Array.Resize(ref decryptedBytes, lastIndex + 1);
        return UTFEncoder.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    }
    public byte[] DecryptBin(byte[] EncryptedValue)
    {
        #region Write the encrypted value to the decryption stream
        MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream decryptStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, DecryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        decryptStream.Write(EncryptedValue, 0, EncryptedValue.Length);
        decryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        #endregion

        #region Read the decrypted value from the stream.
        encryptedStream.Position = 0;
        Byte[] decryptedBytes = new Byte[encryptedStream.Length];
        encryptedStream.Read(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
        encryptedStream.Close();
        #endregion
        return decryptedBytes;
    }

    /// Convert a string to a byte array.  NOTE: Normally we'd create a Byte Array from a string using an ASCII encoding (like so).
    //      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    //      return encoding.GetBytes(str);
    // However, this results in character values that cannot be passed in a URL.  So, instead, I just
    // lay out all of the byte values in a long string of numbers (three per - must pad numbers less than 100).
    public byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("Invalid string value in StrToByteArray");
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        return encoding.GetBytes(str);
        byte val;
        byte[] byteArr = new byte[str.Length / 3];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        do
        {
            val = byte.Parse(str.Substring(i, 3));
            byteArr[j++] = val;
            i += 3;
        }
        while (i < str.Length);
        return byteArr;
    }

    // Same comment as above.  Normally the conversion would use an ASCII encoding in the other direction:
    //      System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    //      return enc.GetString(byteArr);    
    public string ByteArrToString(byte[] byteArr)
    {
        byte val;
        string tempStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= byteArr.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            val = byteArr[i];
            if (val < (byte)10)
                tempStr += "00" + val.ToString();
            else if (val < (byte)100)
                tempStr += "0" + val.ToString();
            else
                tempStr += val.ToString();
        }
        return tempStr;
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can have an explanation/suggestion

Edit : sample usage that i've remotely debugged:

```
            byte[] binData;
            SimpleDES AES = new SimpleDES("xxxxxxx");
            long sz = objRdr.GetBytes(2, 0, null, 0, 0);
            if (sz > 0)
            {
                binData = new byte[sz];
                objRdr.GetBytes(2, 0, binData, 0, binData.Length);
                string Name = AES.Decrypt(binData);
            }
```

Clarification:-
The class might not be cleanly finalized i had issues with padding(AES implementation) but i had to include for reference
The Core of the problem lies in Decrypt method: same key,vector and input byte array resulted in different decrypted byte array

Comment: Use Convert.ToBase64String, or a hex encoding. Your text encoding is suspect (and not cleanly reversible).

Comment: @bartonjs in my remote debugging session of Decrypt method : for the same key,vector and input byte[] EncryptedValue the method resulted in a different(wrong) byte array decryptedBytes  >> this is the issue which i believe is not at text encoding(i'm refering to byte arrays here)

Comment: If the problem is reproducible without the text encoding pieces then they ideally wouldn't be in your code here (the Minimal in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The AES classes and DES classes in .NET are tested several thousand times per day on machines all around the world, and they've never been wrong.  I see you're creating the decryptor object very early instead of once per invocation of decrypt.  That's fine, but you need to be triple-sure that you're not using them across multiple threads, because they're stateful.

Comment: Definitely the crypto classes are not the subject,but the implementation/environment
That's why i've mentioned the production environment(Win Server 2012 R2) and the code,hoping for some hints/guidance(best practices) or if any known issues